# TSQL sysdatabases query returns 'Server Name'

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I use the following query:

```
select name from sys.sysdatabases
```

and get an additional column returned called `Server Name`

Where does this column come from, as it is a handy column to have in ssrs but will not replicate, it only works in Management Studio

Comment: That query should return 1 column.. if you want the server name `select @@SERVERNAME`

Comment: I only get `name` back - the database name - can't reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

## What Probably Happened

My guess is that you opened your query window by right-clicking on a registered server group and choosing "New Query."

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) offers a [feature](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2086/run-sql-commands-against-multiple-sql-servers-without-cms/) where it will run the same query on multiple servers and then combine the results into a single results grid. To help you sort out which server returned which data rows, by default SSMS adds a `Server Name` column to this grid. This feature can be accessed by first adding the servers of interest to the registered servers list and then right-clicking on the relevant registered server group and choosing "New Query."

## How to Achieve the Same Effect in SSMS

Depending on the exact data you want, you can get the executing server's name via the T-SQL variable `@@SERVERNAME` or the `SERVERNAME` property of the `SERVERPROPERTY` function (see the remarks section of MSDN's [documentation on `SERVERPROPERTY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx) for details on the difference between what these two approaches retrun).

For example, if you choose to use`@@SERVERNAME`, you can fetch that name via a stand-alone query (`SELECT @@SERVERNAME`). You can also achieve functionality similar to SSMS's `Server Name` column by adding `, 'Server Name' = @@SERVERNAME` to the end of your SSRS report's SELECT column list (e.g. `SELECT FirstName, LastName, 'Server Name' = @@SERVERNAME FROM ....`).